# Authenticating a CLI application to consume google API services

Tags: python, authentication, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, authorization

I am trying to create a Python CLI application that will need to create, read and write user Google Sheets. The application will be open source, and users are responsible for configuring it to consume Google services, I am struggling with that last part.

#### What I can do

Following the quickstart guide on how to consume Google Sheets API Service, I found that I need to:

1. Create a Google Cloud project.
2. Enable the Google Sheets API.
3. Create an OAuth consent screen.
4. Create credentials that my application can use to authenticate with Google.

#### The problem

With the above process, I have two options:

1. Follow all the steps and authenticate the application using the created credentials. This will use the quota of the project I created and, as I mentioned, I would like the users to have this responsibility.
2. Force the users to create the Google Cloud project. This would give them the responsibility but for me, the process is not worth it for the basic functionalities that the application will bring.

This brings me some questions:

1. How do open-source projects handle this situation when the owners do not want to handle the responsibility while keeping the user efforts as low as possible?
2. Isn't there a way of acting on behalf of the user who signed it via Google in my application, consuming their user quota, similar to a third-party application that can read user data? This was my original intention, "consuming the user quota" somehow. I did not find any information on how to do so or if it is even possible.
3. Is there something I am missing or what am I asking does not have sense?
4. Maybe I am focusing on the REST API but there are other options that could allow me to do the operations (create, write, read) on Google Sheets on the user's behalf?